# A question about the HOD Conjecture

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Is it known what other equivalence the HOD Conjecture has only under the assumption of a supercompact cardinal?

That is, under the assumption of an extendible cardinal $\delta$ (Or even HOD-supercompactness), the HOD Conjecture is equivalent to HOD being a weak extender model for $\delta$ supercompact. Is this still the case if we only assume supercompactness?